# Is it possible to receive a gzipped response via elasticsearch-py?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have an API (via [hug](https://www.hug.rest)) that sits between a UI and Elasticsearch.

The API uses [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) to run searches, for example:

```py
es = Elasticsearch([URL], http_compress=True)

@hug.post('/search')
def search(body):
  return es.search(index='index', body=body)
```

This works fine; however, I cannot figure out how to obtain a compressed JSON result.

Elasticsearch is capable of this because a `curl` test checks out — the following returns a mess of characters to the console instead of JSON and this is what I want to emulate:

```sh
curl -X GET -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' <URL>/<INDEX>/_search
```

I've tried the approach [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/407) to modify HTTP headers, but interestingly enough the `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"` header is already there: it just doesn't appear to be passed to Elastic because the result is always uncompressed.

Lastly, I'm passing `http_compress=True` when creating the Elastic instance; however, this only compresses the payload — not the result.

Has anyone had a similar struggle and figured it out?

Comment: Hello Chris! Any chance you have found the solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: @YibinLin I'm afraid not :(

Comment: I used the following custom header in the Elasticsearch constructor:

    Elasticsearch([es_address], headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"},)

And it seems like it's automatically de-compressing the response from the ES server. May I ask how do you determine if the response is un-compressed? I am using version elasticsearch==7.1.0 in case it is useful.

Comment: Frankly, I don't recall the details — this was over 6 months ago and we were able to move forward without this. Is your approach working?

Comment: It seems like by changing headers I mentioned in my previous comment the response is gzipped. However, the performance/response time is even slower than plain JSON (non-zipped). We ended up using just plain JSON response.